# Maximum call stack size exceeded Crud angular

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, forms, crud

hii i'm working on the crud operations with springboot and angular, i have 4 associated databases client associated with emp and conj, and then i have demande asoociated with client so i exported the classes in angular this is the exported class of demande:

```
import { Client } from "./client";

export class Demande {
    montant!: number;
    client!: Client;

    demande:Demande=new Demande();
```

and this is the client :

```
import { Conj } from "./conj";
import { Emp } from "./emp";

export class Client {
    cin!:number;
    prenom!:string;
    nom!:string;
    numCompte!:string;
    typeHeber!:string;
    dateDel!:Date;
    dateNai!:Date;
    adresse!:string;
    numTel!:number;
    adresseMail!:string;
    genre!:string;
    etatCivil!:string;
    nbEnfants!:number;
    salaireNet!:number;
    profession!:string;
    ficheP!:string;
    assuranceV!:string;
    attestationT!:string;
    conj!:Conj;
    emp!:Emp;
    
  client: Client=new Client();
```

this is a part of the html component:

```
<div class="content">
        <form data-multi-step (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit()" >
          <div class ="card active" data-step>
            
            <div class="user-details">
              <div class="input-box">
                  <span class="details">Numéro Compte</span>
                  <input type="number" id="numCompte" name="numCompte" placeholder="num compte" [(ngModel)]="demande.client.numCompte" min="0" max="100" required>
              </div>
              <div class="input-box">
                  <span class="details">Numéro CIN</span>
                  <input type="number" id="cin" name="cin" placeholder="num CIN" [(ngModel)]="demande.client.cin" min="0" max="100" required>
              </div>
              <div class="input-box">
                  <span class="details">Date Délivrance CIN</span>
                  <input type="date" id="deliCin" name="deliCin" value="2023-04-22" [(ngModel)]="demande.client.dateDel" min="2000-01-01" max="2023-12-31" required>   
              </div>
        
              <div class="input-box">
                <span class="details">Prénom</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="prénom" id="prenom" name="prenom" [(ngModel)]="demande.client.prenom" required>
              </div>
              <div class="input-box">
                  <span class="details">Date Naissance</span>
                  <input type="date" id="dateNai" name="dateNai" value="2023-04-22" [(ngModel)]="demande.client.dateNai" min="2000-01-01" max="2023-12-31" required>   
              </div>
                <div class="input-box">
                  <span class="details">Etat civil</span>
                  <select name="etat" id="etat" [(ngModel)]="demande.client.etatCivil"  >
                    <option value="Célibataire">Célibataire</option>
                    <option value="Marié">Marié(e)</option>
                    <option value="Divorcé">Divorcé(e)</option>
                    <option value="veuf">veuf(veuve)</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                
              <div class="input-box">
                <span class="details">Adresse</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="adress" id="adresse" name="adresse" [(ngModel)]="demande.client.adresse" required>
              </div>
              <div class="input-box">
                  <span class="details">Téléphone</span>
                  <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Téléphone" pattern="^\+216\s\d{2}\d{3}\d{3}$"  [(ngModel)]="demande.client.numTel" required>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box">
                  <span class="details">Adresse mail</span>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="adress mail" name="mail" [(ngModel)]="demande.client.adresseMail" required>
                </div></div>

                <div class="category">
                  <input type="radio" name="cat" value="locataire" id="loc" [(ngModel)]="demande.client.typeHeber">
                    <label for="loc"> Locataire </label>
                  <input type="radio" name="cat" value="proprietaire" id="pro" [(ngModel)]="demande.client.typeHeber">
                    <label for="pro"> Propriétaire </label>
                </div>
              </div>
                     <div class="input-box">
                            <span class="details">Salaire Net</span>
                            <input type="number" placeholder="Salaire Net" name="salaireNet" id="salaireNet" [(ngModel)]="demande.client.salaireNet" required>
                        </div>
                      <div class="input-box">
                          <span class="details">Nombre d'enfants en charge</span>
                              <input type="number" id="nbEnfants" name="nbEnfants" placeholder="Nombres Enfants" [disabled]="demande.client.etatCivil ==='Célibataire'"  [(ngModel)]="demande.client.nbEnfants" >
                      </div>  
                </div>
              <div class="user-details">
                  <div class="input-box">
                      <span class="details">Fiche De Paie</span>
                          <input type="file"id="FP" name="FP" class="file" [(ngModel)]="demande.client.ficheP"  accept="image/png, image/jpg">
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-box">
                      <span class="details">Assurance De Vie</span>
                          <input type="file" class="file" id="AV" name="AV" [(ngModel)]="demande.client.assuranceV" accept="image/png, image/jpg">
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-box">
                    <span class="details">Attestation De Travail</span>
                        <input type="file" class="file" id="AT" name="AT" accept="image/png, image/jpg">
                </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="input-box"></div>
              
              <div class="button">
                <input type="submit" value="Suivant" (click)="activateCard(1)" class="editer">
                <div class="space">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        <div class ="card active" data-step>

          <div class="user-details">
            <div class="input-box">
                <span class="details">Nom Employeur</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Nom Employeur" name="nomEmp" id="nomEmp"  [(ngModel)]="demande.client.employeur.nom"  required>
              </div>

              <div class="input-box">
                <span class="details">Téléphone Employeur</span>
                <input type="tel" id="telEmp" name="telEmp" placeholder="Téléphone Employeur" pattern="^\+216\s\d{2}\d{3}\d{3}$" [(ngModel)]="demande.client.employeur.telEmp"  required>
              </div>
              
              <div class="input-box">
                  <span class="details">Secteur d'activité</span>
                <select name="secteur" id="secteur-select"[(ngModel)]="demande.client.employeur.secteurTrav" >
                    <option value="Agriculture">Agriculture et agroalimentaire</option>
                    <option value="Industrie">Industrie</option>
                    <option value="Energie">Énergie</option>
                    <option value="Commerce">Commerce et artisanat</option>
                    <option value="Tourisme">Tourisme</option>
                    <option value="Recherche">Recherche</option>
                    <option value="Finance">Finance et assurance</option>  
                </select>
              </div>
```

this the component typeScript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Demande } from '../classes/demande';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-creation-demande',
  templateUrl: './creation-demande.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./creation-demande.component.css']
})

export class CreationDemandeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router:Router){} 
  //selectedEtat:string='';

  demande:Demande=new Demande();

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.demande);
  }
```

and this my console and the form won't show up:
[here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NTVe.png)

please help and if ther's anything else not right tell me and thank youu